# Aptana Error, readyState=3?

Tags: installation, aptana

I'm just starting with Aptana Studio. I'm used to using Eclipse as an IDE for Flex. Creating a new HTML/JS project I run the sample boilerplate index.html and get the following error.

> error: [AGENT] socket error: [object Event]; readyState=3. Perhaps
>   Helper is not running on ws://127.0.0.1:6258/2 or is shutting down?

It previews OK but the event seems to fire once per second or so. Suggestions?